# dynamic arrays with more that one column

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need to store different types of DATA inside one same "array" associated to a key (or an ID) in my android application, and I'm wondering if there's a way to create HashMaps (or equivalent dynamic arrays) that have more than one column of content. Like this for example.

```
HashMap<Integer, String, LatLng, Marker> myHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String, LatLng, Marker>();
```

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: A `Map` is something that associates keys to values. What would be a `Map<A,B,C,D>` ? I think you just want a `Map<Object,Object>` even it seems really bad design

Comment: map is just key value pairs.HashMap<Integer, String, LatLng, Marker> makes very little sense

Comment: To make a more sence I'd imagine a variable that stores DATA like a MySQL table. One primary key (for example) and several data. Like this:
|id|message (string)|latitude (double)|longitude (double)|

Comment: `more than one column of content` ->  Use an object for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class Row {
    public Integer i;
    public String s;
    public LatLng ll;

    public Row(Integer i, String s, LatLng ll) {
        this.i = i; 
        this.s = s;
        this.ll = ll;
    }
}

List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
```

<del>This is semi pseudo code but I think you get the idea</del>

Adding new Rows to the list can be done with

```
rows.add(new Row(new Integer(1), "a string", new LatLng(51.448495, 5.470877));
```

Editing a row can be done with

```
rowIndex = 3;
Row row = rows.get(rowIndex);
row.i = 2; //give a new value
//etc
```

Edit: replaced pseude code with real code

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, may I ask why? It's not very different from the answer that received an upvote - I'm here to learn, too

Comment: sorry I put a downvote, it actually was what I was looking for since the DATA are dynamic with your answer, I'll mark it as the solution. But I would like how you'd add a "row" to your map ? Using map.add(object?);

Comment: Would you mind removing the downvote, if it doesn't apply (anymore)?

Comment: thanks a lot, it's way clearer that way.
Dare I ask one more question ? if I want to edit a row, how can I do it with a list ? Couldn't I use a HashMap<Integer, Row> myHashMap ? (I have removed the downvote, someone else put another one, sorry)

Comment: you have no idea of how much this was stucking me during the development of my app :) thank god you were. I don't want to abuse but if I were to have other problems, may I contact you in the future ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63869/discussion-between-gotgot1995-and-tim-castelijns).

Answer (score 1):

map is just a key and value so HashMap makes very little sense

Java does not let you define data structured this way. A collection of type Class A should have hold only instance of Class A or its sub type.

**EDIT:** From the data you have provided seems like you want to process each row from a database table. Most appropriate data structure for it is to have a class with fields that correspond to a database table.

When you fetch a row from the a result set just create an instance of this class.

```
Class mysqlTuple
{
   public Integer id;
   public String message;
   public LatLng latitude;
   public  Marker longitude;
}

mysqlTupe [] mysqlTable = new mysqlTupe [];
```

Comment: That'd be a solution but I want different objects to be linked to the same ID like on a MySQL table.

Comment: pls provide us an example of your data. That would be a lot easier to understand

Comment: I have a MySQL table and my android app downloads it's content through a PHP script that return JSON syntaxed DATA.
My table's structure is that way: |id|message|latitude|longitude|
the thing is I want to process this DATA by row (like when you do a MySQL request and you only want to return the message  linked to the ID number 276 for example).

Comment: hem... thanks a lot for the theoretical point of view, it is actually what I'm trying to do... but more practically, what would it look like ?

Comment: look at the sample code. when accessing a row from the resultset just instantiate the above class and push it onto the array if you want to store them and process later.

Comment: the thing is when you instanciate your class, the datas must have a fixed number of rows, but the DATA will change during the process so... it'd be most likely a List<class> that I should do.

Comment: yup Use an ArryList which is dynamic in nature.It can grow depending on your need

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what you are trying to achieve
One option is to keep 3 different maps:

```
Map<String, Integer>
Map<String,Marker>
Map<String,LatLng>
```

Another option is to make a:

```
Map<String,Object>
```

However you will have to 'instanceof' to check the real type, which is not a best practice.